# Is manual adjustment of AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal useless?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, guidelines, function-comparison

This is a problem confusing me for years.

`AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` are two options that I never truly understand and, to be honest, always avoid touching. Let's first look at the descriptions for them in the document:

> ```
> AccuracyGoal
> ```
>
> is an option for various numerical operations which specifies how many effective digits of accuracy should be sought in the final result.
>
> ```
> PrecisionGoal
> ```
>
> is an option for various numerical operations which specifies how many effective digits of precision should be sought in the final result.

Reading this, one will probably consider these two options as something that **efficiently** control the accuracy and precision of numerical results, but sadly, it's not true. Numerous examples coming out in this site have proved that the option controlling precision and accuracy is `WorkingPrecision`. Just a few examples:

[Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/1871)

[singularity in NDSolve for some values of parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29150/1871)

[NIntegrate fails while Integrate works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23689/1871)

[NSolve gives additional solutions that don't satisfy the equations!](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13947/1871)

As far as I can tell, none of the examples above can be solved by merely adjusting `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`. You can find more by searching `WorkingPrecision`.

Indeed, the behavior of `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` isn't against the description in the document. Just look at the description carefully:

> …should be **sought** in the final result.

and check the **Details**:

> Even though you may specify `PrecisionGoal -> n`, the results you get may sometimes have much less than n‐digit precision.
>
> Even though you may specify `AccuracyGoal -> n`, the results you get may sometimes have much less than n‐digit accuracy.

These words can be interpreted as "The option values of `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` are merely *goals* i.e. they may not be achieved".

However, if the effect of `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` is really that uncontrollable, can I say these options are useless, at least for manual adjustment?

Or, if the root of all evil is just another piece of vague description in the document, what's the accurate usage of these options? Is there a clear enough principle for setting them?

Comment: Although not definitive, the question and answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9161/1063) are somewhat useful.

Comment: It is my understanding that `WorkingPrecision` effectively sets the maximum accuracy and precision that can be obtained in a computation.  However, `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` can be used to obtain a result with a lower accuracy and precision..  This could be useful in a slow computation with, for instance, `FindRoot`, if you need accuracy and precision less than half the `WorkingPrecision`.  Low  `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` would terminate the iterative computation sooner than it otherwise would, saving computer time.

Comment: `WorkingPrecision` is exactly what it says on the tin: the internal algorithms are effectively fed numbers whose precision is set to that particular setting. This is useful for potentially unstable computations, where it is possible to get a result with, say, only 5 digits of accuracy even when the starting inputs have a precision of 30.

Comment: `PrecisionGoal`/`AccuracyGoal` should be thought of as convergence criteria and can have different meaning (usually documented) for different functions. They are indeed just goals, and whether they will be satisfied depends on both the algorithm and the input. Typically a major required ingredient is a sufficiently high `WorkingPrecision`. In fact, the automatic setting of these is often (heuristically) based on the working precision, e.g. for `MachinePrecision` input the default precision goal for `NIntegrate` would be around 6, for `NDSolve` around 8 etc. But your specific mileage may vary.

Answer (score 40):

#### Introduction

The first section below can be found in standard numerical analysis textbooks. Most current textbooks seem to assume a working environment such as MATLAB or a programming language such C, Python, etc. in which there are at most two choices for working precision: single and double.  As a result, `WorkingPrecision` as a parameter is not much discussed in textbooks and could be considered an issue peculiarly related to *Mathematica.*  I explain its role in establishing reliable convergence criteria, which are set by `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`, in the last part of this answer.

#### Stability and conditioning

$\def\x{{\bf x}}\def\y{{\bf y}}\def\A{{\bf A}}$
Suppose $\A$ is an algorithm that for an input $\x$ computes an output $\y$ that satisfies a condition 
$$F(\x,\y)=0\,.$$
Let us use the same symbol $\|\cdot\|$ to denote "***norms***" that measure the "size" of $\x$ and $\y$.
We say $\A$ is ***stable*** if for a sequence $\x_n\rightarrow\x$, the sequence of corresponding outputs $\y_n\rightarrow\y$.
A measure of stability of a solution $(\x,\y)$ is given by the condition number $K$, which we roughly define as the ratio of the relative change in output to the relative change in input, over all sufficiently small changes in input.
Somewhat more formally,
$$K = \sup_{\Delta\x}\left.{\|\Delta\y\|\over\|\y\|}\right/{\|\Delta\x\|\over\|\x\|} \,,$$
where the supremum is taken over all sufficiently small $\Delta\x$, and $\Delta\y$
corresponds to the solution to $F(\x+\Delta\x,\y+\Delta\y)=0$.
What is considered sufficiently small, just like the norm itself, is context-dependent.  The condition number $K$ bounds the factor that multiplies the relative error in the input, the product being equal to relative error in the output.

For a continuous model over the real or complex numbers, the above is probably a sufficient formulation. A floating-point implementation $\A^*$ for a given $\x$ usually computes a solution $\y^*=\y+\Delta\y$ that can be viewed either as a solution corresponding to an input $\x^*=\x+\Delta\x$ satisfying
$$F(\x+\Delta\x,\y+\Delta\y)=0\tag{1}$$
or approximately satisfying the condition, i.e.
$$F(\x,\y+\Delta\y)+\Delta F=0\tag{2}$$
or some other combination of deltas.

It seems to be difficult to give a *general* definition ***numerical stability***.
The discretization of floating point numbers means there are only finitely many inputs, which complicates the consideration of limits and bounds.
At the least in a numerically stable algorithm, the maximum error $\sup{\|\Delta\y\|}$ would decrease as $\sup\|\Delta\x\|$ decreases.
Even more, one might require the condition number $K$ to be bounded.
One might even want $K$ to be relatively small, which we will discuss below in relation to the working precision.  This criterion serves to distinguish ***well-conditioned*** problems ($K$ small) from ***ill-conditioned*** ones ($K$ large).

#### `WorkingPrecision`, `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`

[`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) is fairly straightforward, but
[`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html)
and
[`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html)
are used in different ways in different functions, corresponding roughly to the viewpoints of error in equations (1) and (2) above.

`WorkingPrecision` selects either [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html) 
or sets the number of digits for [`arbitrary-precision numbers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html)
to be used in the computation.
Currently (2018), `MachinePrecision` is most commonly what is called (64-bit) double precision; it corresponds to a setting of [`$MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachinePrecision.html), currently about `15.95`, but without the precision-tracking and extra guard digits of arbitrary-precision numbers.
Setting `WorkingPrecision` has the side effect in most numerical functions of setting the default values for `PrecisionGoal -> Automatic` and/or `AccuracyGoal -> Automatic` to half the working precision.

`PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` are input parameters that are used together to determine a stopping condition in terms of a bound or bounds on the truncation error.  As [@ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118249/is-manual-adjustment-of-accuracygoal-and-precisiongoal-useless#comment319570_118249) remarks, they are goals only, since numerical error estimators, which are subject to their own assumptions and errors, can be wrong.

One type of stopping criterion for `PrecisionGoal ->pg` and `AccuracyGoal -> ag`, discussed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138634/4999) and [Norms in NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveVectorNorm.html), is
$$\|\Delta\y\| < 10^{-ag} + 10^{-pg}\,\|\y\|\tag{3}$$
When $10^{-pg}\,\|\y\| <\mskip-4mu< 10^{-ag}$, the approximation
$$10^{-ag} + 10^{-pg}\,\|\y\| \approx 10^{-ag}$$
implies that if the error indicates that $\y$ is correct to at least $ag$ digits past the decimal point, the algorithm terminates.
And when $10^{-ag} <\mskip-4mu< 10^{-pg}\,\|\y\|$, the approximation
$$10^{-ag} + 10^{-pg}\,\|\y\| \approx 10^{-pg}\,\|\y\|$$
implies that if the error indicates that $\y$ is correct to at least the leading $pg$ digits, the algorithm terminates. Thus depending on how $\|\y\|$ varies, 
the stopping criterion can be dominated by precision or accuracy.
This sort of criterion is used in `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate`.

The other type of stopping criterion is
$$\|\Delta\y\| < 10^{-pg}\,\|\y\|
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 \|\Delta F\| < 10^{-ag}\tag{4}$$
This sort is used by `FindRoot` and related functions.  In `FindRoot[f[y] == x, {y, y0}]`, the "accuracy" error $\|\Delta F\|$ is `Norm[{f[y]} - {x}]`.

**The relationship between `WorkingPrecision` and error goals.**
Suppose for the condition number and error goals, we have $K = 10^8$ and `PrecisionGoal -> 8`, `AccuracyGoal -> 8`.  At a working precision (WP) of double precision (DP), or the usual `MachinePrecision`, we have a machine epsilon, or 
`$MachineEpsilon`, of
$$\epsilon_{WP} = \epsilon_{DP} = 2^{-52} \approx 2 \times 10^{-16}\,.$$
In other words there are nearly 16 digits of precision, or an uncertainty in the input of $\epsilon_{WP}/2$.

The condition number $K$ implies we could lose up to 8 of the digits of precision, leaving around 8 in the computed answer $\y$.
With luck, it will satisfy the precision goal, but we shouldn't be surprised if sometimes it does not.  We should not expect that raising `PrecisionGoal` will improve the result at all.  If we're lucky, *Mathematica* will complain that the error goals cannot be met (e.g. the messages `FindRoot::lstol`, `NIntegrate::slwcon`, etc.).
Whether raising `AccuracyGoal` has any effect depends on how the error is measured and on the size of $\|\y\|$.

For error measured by (3), we have the following.
If $\|\y\| \ge 1$, then `AccuracyGoal` in effect sets a relative precision goal of at least $ag$, which will not help when raised above the setting of `PrecisionGoal`.  If $\|\y\| <\mskip-4mu<1$, then `PrecisionGoal -> 8` implies more than 8 accurate digits after the decimal point,
but `AccuracyGoal -> 8` means the algorithm stops at 8;
therefore raising `AccuracyGoal` could be expected to improve the solution.

For error measured by (4), the effect of raising `AccuracyGoal` depends on $F(\x,\y)$.
The question of whether for a given solution $\y^*$ there is an update $\delta\y$ so that $F(\x,\y^*+\delta\y)+\delta F=0$ and $\|\delta F\| < \|\Delta F(\x,\y^*)\|$.
For instance, if the norm of the Jacobian of $F$ is too large, it may not be possible at the specified working precision to find an update $\delta\y$ such that $\y + \delta\y \ne \y$ and the error is reduced.  In such a case, raising the accuracy goal would not help (see [this example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51098/nsolve-for-high-degree-univariate-polynomials/51257#51257)).

For both measures, `AccuracyGoal` can be seen as setting a limit $10^{-ag}$ below which numbers may be assumed to be equivalent to zero.  For instance, `NIntegrate` has as a default `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity`, which causes it to complain when a numerical integral converges to, but does not exactly equal, zero (`NIntegrate::slwcon`).  Setting `AccuracyGoal` to a finite value tells how small the approximation needs to be in order to be considered close enough to zero.

Here is another way to look at it:
At a fixed working precision, there are only finitely many possibilities for $\y$.
Among them, there is one with least error.
If that error meets or exceeds the error bounds set by `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`, then adjusting the goals will not result in a better solution.
Further, if the conditioning is bad, then the error may vary wildly in the neighborhood of the true solution, making finding the optimal solution like searching for a needle in a haystack. 
If, on the other hand, the least possible error is much less than the error bounds,
then increasing `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` can result in better solutions.

Increasing working precision increases the number of possibilities for $\y$. It also ameliorates the effects of poor conditioning. For instance, if we set `WorkingPrecision -> 24` and $K = 10^{8}$, we might expect around 16 digits of precision in the computed solution.  Then raising the goals would have an effect.

In practice, there are other issues.  One does not know the optimal answer, sometimes not even approximately.  Sometimes one does not have a good idea about the conditioning. (For some problems, you can evaluate the objective function at arbitrary precision numbers and see how many digits are lost, the number lost giving a lower bound on how much to raise WP.)  Some of the analysis above assumes the algorithm starts close to the true answer (i.e., the initial error is sufficiently small).  Error goals and working precision cannot solve these issues (except maybe for the conditioning).

Here are three reasons for raising `WorkingPrecision` (the first two were mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135968/4999)):

- One cannot achieve the precision and accuracy goals at the current WP.  In such a case, raise WP but also manually set `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` to their current values (don't raise them).
- One wants to raise `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`, and a higher WP is needed.
- One wants to test numerical stability: If the result is stable under higher and higher settings of WP, then it is evidence of numerical stability at the initial WP.

Comment: This was a very informative, well-written article which has cleared up a lot of my misunderstandings with these things. Thank you Michael E2.

Comment: Very nice answer. But one thing you sort of hint at but don't detail, is that these two options can be lowered to produce an answer faster when you only need a rough guess,  for instance in FindRoot, while still using the faster machine precision.

Comment: @KraZug True, my focus was on using the options to achieve some goal. The use-case where I most commonly lower the goals is in a multidimensional `NIntegrate[]`

Comment: This is a great answer, it solved my issue. However, I would like to point out that the FindRoot documentation (Mathematica 13.2.1) is contradictory. It states that "FindRoot continues until either of the goals specified by AccuracyGoal or PrecisionGoal is achieved.". You pointed out this is not he case. For `FindRoot` there are *two independent* conditions: even if the `PrecisionGoal` condition is achieved there will be an error if `AccuracyGoal` is too high. `NDSolve`, for instance, does not have this behaviour. So it seems that there is a problem in the documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Though `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` are subtle, there do exist cases in which manual adjustment of them is **not** useless:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138634/1871

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119871/1871

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143163/1871

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156190/1871

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163212/1871

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/196886/4999

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244303/1871

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271281/1871

Comment: "there do exist cases" makes it sound a bit like they are mostly useless...

Comment: @ilian Yeah that's what I implied 囧. You see, there are very few examples solving by _manual adjusting_ these 2 options in this site at the moment. Considering the current situation, I think it's reasonable to say they're mostly useless…

Comment: I believe the "ignore the convergence warning if the answer looks good enough" method is more popular ;-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thx. (You can directly add this to the answer, this is a community wiki :) )

Answer (score 6):

> `PrecisionGoal`/`AccuracyGoal` should be thought of as convergence
>   criteria and can have different meaning (usually documented) for
>   different functions. They are indeed just goals, and whether they will
>   be satisfied depends on both the algorithm and the input. Typically a
>   major required ingredient is a sufficiently high `WorkingPrecision`.
>   In fact, the automatic setting of these is often (heuristically) based
>   on the working precision, e.g. for `MachinePrecision` input the
>   default precision goal for `NIntegrate` would be around 6, for
>   `NDSolve` around 8 etc. But your specific mileage may vary.

(via comment by [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian), per suggestion of another user)