# Difficult to Evaluate Numerical Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Any tips for evaluating the integral

$$
I_{2n} = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \: \text{sech}(\pi x) \text{sech}(\pi y)\tanh^{2n}(\pi(x-y)) \: \text{d}x \text{d}y?
$$

in a numerical but precise fashion? In particular, I'm interested in guessing the exact answer from the resultant decimal expression. Here's the current attempt ($2n = 8$):

```
exp = NIntegrate[1/2 π Sech[π x] Sech[π y] Tanh[π(x-y)]^8,       
    {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 10];

Rationalize[exp, 10^-5]
```

Mathematica can easily do $2n =4,6$ with NIntegrate, but begins to run into problems for $2n = 8,10$ (values of interest). I've played around with various settings, but none seem to help.

Comment: Those dx and dy should be on the end.

Comment: The code has been added.

Comment: Your current run is working properly and produces `149/219`.

Comment: Just remove , `PrecisionGoal` you will get `47/74` in the case `2n=10`.

Comment: For more on `PrecisionGoal` read this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118249/is-manual-adjustment-of-accuracygoal-and-precisiongoal-useless

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I cannot reproduce the problem the user is experiencing

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any problem. The integral seems to be well-behaved.

```
int[n_] :=
  NIntegrate[
    1/2 π Sech[π x] Sech[π y] Tanh[π (x - y)]^(2 n), {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]]
vals = Table[int[n], {n, 6}]
```

> `{1., 0.833333, 0.741667, 0.680357, 0.635144, 0.599776}`

```
vals = Table[int[n], {n, 6}]
ListPlot[vals]
```

[image: plot]

These results obtained running V11.0.1 on OS X 10.10.2

Comment: Is the `Block` necessary? `NIntegrate` already localises x and y

Comment: @SimonWoods. I forgot that.