# FindMinimum ignoring Accuracy/Precision Goals

Tags: mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy

If I use `FindMinimum` on a function of one variable, `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` will find a solution to the required accuracy/precision, which will be quicker as it requires less evaluations:

```
test1[a_?NumericQ] := Module[{},
  Abs[x[1]]/.NDSolve[{x''[t] == a x[t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0},x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]] ]

Block[{c=0}, {FindMinimum[test1[a], {a,1}, AccuracyGoal -> 1, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 1, Method -> "PrincipalAxis", EvaluationMonitor :> c++], c}]

{{0.000711985, {a -> -2.46516}}, 17}

Block[{c=0}, {FindMinimum[test1[a], {a,1}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis",  EvaluationMonitor :> c++], c}]

{{7.55525*10^-15, {a -> -2.4674}}, 35}
```

However, when I have a function of two variables, it seems to ignore the goals:

```
test2[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Module[{},
  Abs[x[1]] /.NDSolve[{x'[t] == a + b x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]]  ]

Block[{c = 0}, {FindMinimum[test2[a, b], {a, 1}, {b, 1}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 1, EvaluationMonitor :> c++],c}]

{{1.72234*10^-9, {a -> -0.611427, b -> -0.914679}}, 232}

Block[{c = 0}, {FindMinimum[test2[a, b], {a, 1}, {b, 1}, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> c++], c}]

{{1.72234*10^-9, {a -> -0.611427, b -> -0.914679}}, 232}
```

As my function takes about 5 seconds to evaluate and I only care about getting the values to ~2 decimal places, this makes a big difference to how long it takes for the `FindMinimum` to terminate. Is there a way to get `FindMinimum` to respect my goals? Or a workaround to get it to stop when it keeps evaluating around the same point to get closer to the root.

I'm using *v11.0.0*, but it does the same on *v9*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in

[Is manual adjustment of AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal useless?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871)

`PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` are subtle in my opinion. According to my personal experience, adjusting `WorkingPrecision` is usually more effective when dealing with precision/accuracy issue, and your case seems not to be an exception:

```
Block[{c = 0}, {FindMinimum[test2[a, b], {a, 1}, {b, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> c++,
     WorkingPrecision -> 4], c}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.092071, {{0.001083, {a -> -0.6112, b -> -0.9201}}, 52}} *)
```

BTW, for your specific example, using `ParametricNDSolveValue` instead of the `_?NumericQ` trick will speed up the calculation further:

```
test3 = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == a + b x[t], x[0] == 1}, Abs@x[1], {t, 0, 1}, {a, b}];

Block[{c = 0}, {FindMinimum[test3[a, b], {a, 1}, {b, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> c++,
     WorkingPrecision -> 4], c}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.041535, {{0.001083, {a -> -0.6112, b -> -0.9201}}, 52}} *)
```

Comment: Yes, the specific example is as usual just a toy, my actual system is much more complicated, with a very large coupled set of ODEs.