# Working precision problem in Complex integrand

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I'm trying to plot 2d numeric integral of a complex function which is actually real. First problem - small non zero complex part, I was forced to plot RE of it. Second - I'm using only exact numbers but got `General::precw` warning and can't tune `WorkingPrecision`! 
The output interpolation is very rough and I have no clue how to deal with it.
My code:

```
c[x_, y_] := (x*u + (1 - u)*y + 4*u*(1 - u)*k^2)^(1/2)
a = 1
W[r_, k_] := (2 Exp[-2*I*k*r])/(Pi^3 a^3)*
   NIntegrate[
   Exp[4*I*u*r*k]*
    u*(1 - u)*(3/4 Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1]]/c[1, 1]^5 + 
      3/2 (Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1]]*r)/c[1, 1]^4 + (Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1]]*r^2)/
      c[1, 1]^3), {u, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
Plot3D[r^2*k^2*W[r, k], {r, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Comment: You were too quick to accept my answer, recommend that you accept Michael E2's answer as it is much better.

Comment: @BobHanlon yeah, I'm newbie in SE and thought changing accepted answer will be not fair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some recommendations:

- Since the integral is provably real, use [`Re`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html) on the integral instead of [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html), since `Chop` will chop small real parts, too.
- To speed things up slightly, use `Re` on the ***integrand***, since [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) will compute with real numbers instead complex ones. Simplify it beforehand so that no complex results are generated in computing the integral.
- To speed things up further, use a higher setting of Gauss points in the `"GaussKronrodRule"`.  The integrand is fairly smooth and not very oscillatory, and higher setting leads to a quickly converging integral.
- Since it is a well-behaved integral, a high `WorkingPrecision` is unnecessary. Using `MachinePrecision` will speed things up even more.
- The plot is ragged because of scaling: The variation in height ($\approx 10^{-3}$) is so small that the plot is virtually flat (in the standard unscaled Euclidean geometry) and ***`Plot3D` does no recursive subdivision, no matter what the setting of `MaxRecursion`.***
- To fixed the raggedness, one can increase the `PlotPoints`, which is somewhat wasteful, or scale the function, so that the automatic adaptive algorithm works effectively; then rescale the result.
- For another speed improvement when plotting, lower the `PrecisionGoal` in `NIntegrate`.  Since the integrand converges quickly, you might risk being bold and assume the actual error is much less than the error estimate `NIntegrate` calculates.  In any case, three or four digits of precision is usually enough for plotting.
- There's an ***error*** in the coding of `W[]` and `c[]`.  In `W[r, k]`, the value of `k` will not be passed to the body of `c[1, 1,]`.  It has the appearance of working because `Plot3D[]` uses [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) to temporarily set the global value of `k`.  Thus, while `Plot3D` is being computed, the parameter `k` in `W[r, k]` and the symbol `k` in `c[1, 1]` happen to have the same value.  Try evaluating `W[2, 3]` with the OP's code and you get an error.

OP's refactored code (thanks to @xzczd for suggesting `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0`):

```
ClearAll[c, W];
c[x_, y_, k_] := (x*u + (1 - u)*y + 4*u*(1 - u)*k^2)^(1/2);   (* N.B. argument  k *)
a = 1;
$pg = Automatic;  (* symbol  $pg  for  PrecisionGoal  setting in  NIntegrate[] *)
Block[{u, k, r},  (* protect symbols while definition is constructed *)
 With[{integrand = 
    Simplify[(2 Exp[-2*I*k*r])/(Pi^3 a^3) Exp[4*I*u*r*k]*
        u*(1 - u)*(3/4 Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1, k]]/c[1, 1, k]^5 +     (* N.B. argument  k *)
          3/2 (Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1, k]]*r)/
            c[1, 1, k]^4 + (Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1, k]]*r^2)/c[1, 1, k]^3) // 
       Re // ComplexExpand,
     0 < k < 5 && 0 < r < 5 && 0 < u < 1]},
  W[r_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
    integrand,
    {u, 0, 1},
    Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, "Points" -> 11},
    PrecisionGoal -> $pg, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
  ]
 ]
```

Timing comparison for different precision goals:

```
Block[{$pg = 3},   (* low setting for  PrecisionGoal  in  NIntegrate[] *)
   Table[W[r, k], {r, 0., 5., 0.1}, {k, 0., 5., 0.1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {4.4409, Null}  *)

Block[{$pg = 8},    (* ~default setting for  PrecisionGoal  in  NIntegrate[] *)
   Table[W[r, k], {r, 0., 5., 0.1}, {k, 0., 5., 0.1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {10.9349, Null}  *)
```

*The unscaled plot.* Raising `MaxRecursion` has no effect:

```
 Block[{$pg = 3},
 Plot3D[r^2*k^2*W[r, k] // Re, {r, 0, 5},
  {k, 0, 5},
  MaxRecursion -> 15,
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
 ]
```

[image]

*The scaled plot.* The default `MaxRecursion` is nearly perfect when the plot is scaled so that scale of each axis are approximately the same. *Update:* I tried `ScalingFunctions` earlier, but I must have done something wrong. It does work, but in this case, the ticks are not as nice as the manual scaling (see below).

```
Block[{$pg = 3},
 Plot3D[r^2*k^2*W[r, k] // Re, {r, 0, 5},
  {k, 0, 5},
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, {10^4 # &, 10^-4 # &}},
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
 ]
```

[image]

The previous scaled plot code produces nicer ticks:

```
 Block[{$pg = 3, scale = 1.*^4},
 Plot3D[scale*r^2*k^2*W[r, k] // Re, {r, 0, 5},
   {k, 0, 5},
   PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic] /. 
  gc_GraphicsComplex :> Scale[gc, {1., 1., 1/scale}, {0., 0., 0.}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful! Why the answer is only 1 post...

Comment: @satoru Thanks! (If I understand your why question, all I can say is that a good answer ought to address all the issues.)

Comment: `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` will speed up the code even further :)

Comment: @xzczd Sometimes it helps only a little and is not worth worrying about, but it's significant in this case.  I should've checked it earlier. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** based on comment by [`Michael E2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) definition of `c` changed to make dependence on `u` and `k` explicit

```
Clear[c];
c[x_, y_, u_, k_] := (x*u + (1 - u)*y + 4*u*(1 - u)*k^2)^(1/2)    
    a = 1;
```

Since `W` uses numerical techniques, its arguments should be restricted with [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html). Use [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to eliminate imaginary artifacts.

```
W[r_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] :=
 (2 Exp[-2*I*k*r])/(Pi^3 a^3)*
   NIntegrate[Exp[4*I*u*r*k]*u*(1 - u)*
     (3/4 Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1, u, k]]/c[1, 1, u, k]^5 +
       3/2 (Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1, u, k]]*r)/c[1, 1, u, k]^4 +
       (Exp[-2*r*c[1, 1, u, k]]*r^2)/c[1, 1, u, k]^3), {u, 0, 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Chop
```

You can improve the smoothness of the plot with [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and/or [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) although these will slow down the evaluation.

```
Plot3D[r^2*k^2*W[r, k], {r, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 5},
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 5] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Helps a lot, now i will use this nice interpolation for my further computations.

Comment: You might want to try evaluating `W` on its own, say `W[1, 1]`. There's a coding error in the OP that you might want to fix in your answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - thanks, correction made.