# NMinimize - function involves a very small number, solution is wrong

Tags: mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy

NMinimize apparently doesn't worry much about the accuracy of small numbers in the result - They don't contribute much to the overall accuracy. Example:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - 1)^2 - 10^-20 (y - 2)^2
NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

yields `{-1.75769*10^-20, {x -> 1., y -> 0.674219}}` rather than `{x->1,y->2}`.

Is there a way to fix this, without knowing the nature of `f[x,y]`?

Comment: The question itself is wrong. `f[x,y]` doesn't have a global minimum. Try e.g. `f[1, 10^10] // N`

Comment: If `+`, then it's a simple machine-precision rounding-error problem (due to the `10^-20`). It doesn't take much to make the second term effectively vanish (adding it doesn't change the value) at machine precision.  (See `$MachineEpsilon`.)  Any working precision of 21 digits or higher gives the correct result: `NMinimize[(x - 1)^2 + 10^-20 (y - 2)^2, {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 21]`.

Answer (score 4):

As @xzczd pointed out, for a minimum to exist the coefficient of the second term should be positive. After doing that, you can improve accuracy by playing with [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html), [`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html), or [`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html). Here's one example:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - 1)^2 + 10^-20 (y - 2)^2
NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y}]
(* Output: {1.75769*10^-20, {x -> 1., y -> 0.674219}}*)
NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y}, AccuracyGoal -> 40]
(* Output: {6.70318*10^-29, {x -> 1., y -> 1.99992}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a bad example, and changing the sign makes it a good example. I will try fixing the more complicated problem with your suggestion, and I am optimistic. I was thinking there was some option I could set to specify a relative rather than absolute error to each result.

Comment: `Accuracy` and `Precision` are relative and not absolute. It's a bit delicate. have a look at this: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html

Comment: `NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]`

Comment: @paul Also, check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871 I should say after the modification by yohbs, the example becomes interesting. Manual adjustment of `AccuracyGoal` is useful in this case! Still, I'd like to point out it's not necessary to use a high `AccuracyGoal`, try `NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 25, AccuracyGoal -> 1]`