# Applying NDSolve to a multi-layer problem (three coupled PDEs)

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following governing equations via `NDSolve`.

[image]

The system consists of three layers. The following shows how I constructed a numerical model my system with given parameter values:

```
rw = 0.01;
er = 0.5;
ez = er;
D2 = 1;
Dp = 0.1;
bp = 1;
b1 = 5;
b2 = 5;
R1 = 1;
R2 = 1;
Rp = 1;
λ1 = 0;
λ2 = λ1;
λp = λ1;
Q = 1;
θ1 = 0.5;
θ2 = 0.5;
θp = 0.5;
A = Q/(2*Pi*θ1*b1);
C0 = 10;
vp = 0.1;
v2 = 0.1;
R = 10;
NR[z_] := If[z <= b1, R1, If[b1 < z < b1 + bp, Rp, R2]];
Ner[z_] := If[z <= b1, er, Exp[-10000 z]];
Nez[z_] := If[z <= b1, ez, If[b1 < z < b1 + bp, (Dp*vp)/A, (D2*v2)/A]];
Nv[z_] := If[z <= b1, Exp[-10000 z], If[b1 < z < b1 + bp, vp, v2]]; 
NA[z_] := If[z <= b1, A, Exp[-10000 z]]; 
sys = 
  {NR[z]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][NC][r, z, t] == 
    (A*Ner[z]*Derivative[2, 0, 0][NC][r, z, t] + 
      (A*Ner[z] + NA[z])/r*Derivative[1, 0, 0][NC][r, z, t]) + 
      A*Nez[z]*Derivative[0, 2, 0][NC][r, z, t] - 
      Nv[z]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][NC][r, z, t],
  NC[rw, z, t] == C0,
  NC[R, z, t] == Exp[-10000 z],
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][NC][r, 0, t] == Exp[-10000 r],
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][NC][r, b1 + bp + b2, t] == Exp[-10000 r],
  NC[r, z, 0] == Exp[-10000 r]}; 
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    sys, NC, {r, rw, R}, {z, 0, b1 + bp + b2}, {t, 0, 100}, 
    Method -> "BDF", AccuracyGoal -> 24, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

The coefficients are a function of z; thus, the governing equations are suitable for each governing equation of the three layers.

To validate the numerical results, I derived a semi-analytical solution as a reference. The code producing the reference is longer than I am permitted to post, so I can not include its code here.

The numerical results seem to be unstable and give the totally difference from reference solution.

```
Show[
  Plot[Evaluate[NC[r, 2.5, 100] /. sol], {r, rw, R}, PlotRange -> All], 
  ListPlot[RR, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

The solid line is the numerical result and the dotted line is the  reference solution,

Can you see any problems with the way I am handling the numerical model for the three layers? Do you have any suggestion about dealing with this kind problem?

Answer (score 5):

It's because you've made at least one simple mistake when coding the equation. Check the `A Ner[z] + NA[z]` part carefully. It's a very bad idea to change the form of the equation when coding it, you should make the equations in the code and in the original text as similar as possible.

A trivial issue is those `Exp[10000 …]` doesn't make sense in your code, if you're trying to omit the `ibcinc` warning, you still need to adjust their coefficients carefully. In your case the inconsistency doesn't cause trouble, so let it be.

Another trivial issue is the adjustion for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` doesn't make sense here. For more informatin, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871).

Here's my attempt for coding your equation:

```
pw[part1_, part2_, part3_] = 
  Piecewise[{{part1, 0 < z < b1}, {part2, b1 < z < b1 + bp}}, part3];
coedt[z_] = pw[R1, Rp, R2];
coedr2[z_] = pw[er A, 0, 0];
coedr[z_] = pw[(er A) (1 - 1/er)/r, 0, 0];
coedz2[z_] = pw[(er A) ez/er, Dp, D2];
coedz[z_] = pw[0, vp, v2];

sys = With[{NC = NC[r, z, t]},
           {coedt[z] D[NC, t] == coedr2[z] D[NC, r, r] + coedr[z] D[NC, r] + 
                                 coedz2[z] D[NC, z, z] - coedz[z] D[NC, z],
            NC == C0 /. r -> rw, NC == 0 /. r -> R, 
            D[NC, z] == 0 /. z -> 0, D[NC, z] == 0 /. z -> b1 + bp + b2, 
            NC == 0 /. t -> 0}];

sol = NDSolve[sys, NC, {r, rw, R}, {z, 0, b1 + bp + b2}, {t, 0, 100}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Plot[Evaluate[NC[r, 2.5, 100] /. sol], {r, rw, R}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm deeply appreciated about your instructions and steers again.