# Accuracy goal and precision goal

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

What they do in our calculation I read about these from internet so, the major doubt is if my output is coming say like 2.215478*10^-18 and I put precision goal or accuracy goal 17. Is this result correct??

If precision goal and accuracy goal taken care of digit after decimal so in this case mathematica consider 17 digit after 2 or it is considering 0.00000000000000000221548 like this because in my calculation if I am increasing my accuracy goal to 18 or 19 then it shows me some error about convergence.
Which output is correct and does it depend upon input parameter.

If anyone can help me to figure this I am so grateful for the same. Thank you

Comment: I didn't get exact answer can't you explain this in easy term please??

Comment: If anything was not adequately explained in the linked thread, please edit your question to include what is still unclear, and then we can reopen.

Comment: I think if you include your actual example, people might help you diagnose what's going on.

Comment: this is my actual problem I didn't get what they are doing in code and how they are considering numerical number in this?? in definition point of view mathematica gave same definition.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am telling you to include the code that is using these settings, so we can pinpoint what's confusing you.

Comment: I think the explanation in the link above is clear enough. If you don't have the patience to read through the whole post, at least read [this comment from ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118249/is-manual-adjustment-of-accuracygoal-and-precisiongoal-useless#comment319570_118249).