# AccuracyGoal & PrecisionGoal: how to know which was used to yield the result?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, options, internals

With `NMinimize` (or many other functions), when an answer is found without any warnings, this means that a certain convergence criterium was achieved. It could be that the convergence specified in `AccuracyGoal` was achieved, or the one given by `PrecisionGoal`. A pedestrian way to know which one was used is to redo the computations a couple of times changing the values of those options. But this is not feasible in my case.

How to know which convergence criterium was used? Say, could one print the criterium along with the answer, without computing the expression more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a hook to `` Optimization`NMinimizeDump`converge `` to capture the errors (in the input `xstep` and in the objective function `fstep`):

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Optimization`NMinimizeDump`converge},
 PrependTo[DownValues@Optimization`NMinimizeDump`converge,
  HoldPattern[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`converge[args__] /; ! TrueQ[$in]] :> 
   Block[{$in = True},
    {xStep, xNew, fStep, fNew, atol, rtol} = {args};
    Optimization`NMinimizeDump`converge[args]]
  ];
 NMinimize[Sin[Tan[x]/2], x, AccuracyGoal -> 9, PrecisionGoal -> 8]
 ]
{xStep, xNew, fStep, fNew, atol, rtol}
% /. {xStep_, xNew_, fStep_, fNew_, atol_, rtol_} :>
  {LessEqual[Norm[xStep] / (atol + rtol * Norm[xNew]), 1 / 2]
   , LessEqual[Norm[fStep] / (atol + rtol * Norm[fNew]), 1 / 2]
   (*,Less[Min[fStep / (1 + fNew + -fStep)], -1000]*)}
(*
  {-1., {x -> -1.26263}}
  {{0.}, {-1.26263}, {0.}, {-1.}, 1/1000000000, 1/100000000}
  {True, True}
*)
```

The parameter `atol` ia the absolute tolerance defined by `AccuracyGoal` and `rtol` is the relative tolerance defined by `PrecisionGoal`.  The `LessEqual` comparisons are the criteria for determining convergence.  (The commented criterion is the test for divergence.)

Each numerical function uses different criteria, which are implemented each in their own way.  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139311/4999) for a general discussion of the ways `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` determine convergence criteria.  The OP mentioned `NMinimize` explicitly, which is the command I looked into.