# Three nonlinearly coupled PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I am new to Mathematica and I need it to solve a system of three nonlinearly coupled PDEs.

$\frac{n_1}{c_0} \frac{\partial E_1}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial E_1}{\partial x} = i\frac{\omega_1}{2n_1 c_0} {\chi}^{(2)} g(x)E_2 E_3 e^{-i\Delta k x} $

$\frac{n_2}{c_0} \frac{\partial E_2}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial E_2}{\partial x} = i\frac{\omega_2}{2n_2 c_0} {\chi}^{(2)} g(x)E_1 E_3^{*} e^{i\Delta k x} $

$\frac{n_3}{c_0} \frac{\partial E_3}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial E_3}{\partial x} = i\frac{\omega_3}{2n_3 c_0} {\chi}^{(2)} g(x)E_1 E_2^{*} e^{i\Delta k x} $

These equations represent the nonlinear three wave-mixing under the slowly varying envelope approximation, in the situation of difference- frequency-generation. The Pump wave ($E_1$) has a Gaussian shape, while the other two waves are orders of magnitude smaller background fields made out of randomly-phased harmonic fields ($E_2$ & $E_3$). Additionally, one of the waves ($E_3$) counter-propagates relative to the other two.

My efforts to solve this with NDSolve were proven unsuccessful, as even when I de-couple the equations (by setting $g(x)=0$) or assume phase matching $\Delta k=0$, I get bad results. When StepSize is large I get some unwanted/unphysical ripples mostly for the counter propagating wave.
[[image: Results for <span class=]$\E_3$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRZZI.jpg)
When I decrease the StepSize, the ripples start to show in the second background field ($E_2$), while the results for the counter-propagating wave gets completely wrong together with NDSolve::eerr warning.
[[image: Results for <span class=]$E_3$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBqos.png)
One of things I notice is that I get different results when changing the amplitude of the waves, although when de-coupled the solutions should only scale.

Although I tried to tweak several of the NDSolver options and configurations I couldn’t make it work. This is even before I turn on the coupling and/or experiments with different parameters. I included my code (also share my [NOTEBOOK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GJxqyQ1oO7cpOSLjRmsUV985ntuCT3Ks/view?usp=sharing)) and it would be amazing if someone could help me out. Thanks.

```
(* Parameters *)
c0 = 0.2998; (* speed of light in [um/fs] *)
n1 = 2.3;
n2 = 2.1;
n3 = 2;
L = 100; (* [um] *)
lam0P = 1.064; (* [um] *)
lam0I = 2.0; (* [um] *)
lam0S = 1/(lam0P^-1 - lam0I^-1); (* [um] *)
chi2 = 8*10^-6 ; (* [um/V] *)
ax = 1.0; (* chi2 modulation length [um] *)
tauP = 150; (* pulse duration [fs] *)
T = L*n1/c0 + 5*tauP; (*max time for evaluation*)
A = 100; (* [um^2] *)
E01 = 10000; (* Pump Peak E [V/um]*)
E0 = 0.0845; (* background fields amplitude [V*um]*)
nx = 4; (*number of points in a domain*)

(* Other variables *)
om1 = c0/n1*2*Pi/lam0P
om2 = c0/n2*2*Pi/lam0S
om3 = c0/n3*2*Pi/lam0I
E02 = (n2*L*lam0S*A)^(-1/2) * E0; (*background modes amplitudes*)
E03 = (n3*L*lam0I*A)^(-1/2) * E0;
omc2 = Pi*c0/(L*n2); (*background modes frequencies*)
omc3 = Pi*c0/(L*n3);
Pulse[t_] := Exp[-(t - 3*tauP)^2/tauP^2];
g[x_] = 0; (* SquareWave[x/ax-ax/nx*0.25]; *)  (* \[Chi]2 modulation *)
Phibg = I*RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, 8]; (*random phases*)
 
(* Equations, Boundaries and Initial Conditions *)
(*coupled PDEs*)
eq1 = D[E1[x, t], t] == -c0 /n1*(D[E1[x, t], x] + I*om1/(n1*c0)*chi2*g[x]*E2[x, t]*E3[x, t]);
eq2 = D[E2[x, t], t] == -c0/n2*(D[E2[x, t], x] + I*om2/(n2*c0)*chi2*g[x]*E1[x, t]*Conjugate[E3[x, t]]);
eq3 = D[E3[x, t], t] == c0/n3*(D[E3[x, t], x] + I*om3/(n3*c0)*chi2*g[x]*E1[x, t]*Conjugate[E2[x, t]]);
 
(* initial conditions *)
ic1 := E1[x, 0] == E01 * Pulse[0];
ic2 := E2[x, 0] == E02*(Exp[I*omc2*n2/c0*x + Phibg[[1]]] + Exp[I*2*omc2*n2/c0*x + Phibg[[2]]] + Exp[I*3*omc2*n2/c0*x + Phibg[[3]]] + Exp[I*4*omc2*n2/c0*x + Phibg[[4]]]);
ic3 := E3[x, 0] == E03*(Exp[-I*omc3*n3/c0*x + Phibg[[5]]] + Exp[-I*2*omc3*n3/c0*x + Phibg[[6]]] + Exp[-I*3*omc3*n3/c0*x + Phibg[[7]]] + Exp[-I*4*omc3*n3/c0*x + Phibg[[8]]]);
(*boundary conditions*)
bc1 := E1[-L/2, t] == E01 * Pulse[t];
bc2 := E2[-L/2, t] == E02*(Exp[-I*omc2*t -I*omc2*n2/c0*L/2 + Phibg[[1]]] + Exp[-I*2*omc2*t - I*omc2*n2/c0*L + Phibg[[2]]] +Exp[-I*3*omc2*t - I*3*omc2*n2/c0*L/2 + Phibg[[3]]] + Exp[-I*4*omc2*t - I*2*omc2*n2/c0*L + Phibg[[4]]]);
bc3 := E3[L/2, t] == E03*(Exp[-I*omc3*t - I*omc3*n3/c0*L/2 + Phibg[[5]]] + Exp[-I*2*omc3*t - I*omc3*n3/c0*L + Phibg[[6]]] + Exp[-I*3*omc3*t - I*3*omc3*n3/c0*L/2 + Phibg[[7]]] + Exp[-I*4*omc3*t - I*2*omc3*n3/c0*L + Phibg[[8]]]);

sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, ic1, ic2, ic3, bc1, bc2, bc3}, {E1,E2,E3}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {t, 0, T}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinStepSize" -> ax/(2*nx), "MaxStepSize" -> ax/(2*nx)}}]
```

Comment: Hi AbirT, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please take the [tour] so you familiarize yourself with the expectations on this site. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. It's unlikely many people will download your notebook. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to offer a minimum working example of code.

Comment: Which version are you in? What option combinations did you try? In _v12.3.1_ with `sol = NDSolveValue[……, {E1, E2, E3}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {t, 0, T}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 200, 
       "MinPoints" -> 200, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}, MaxStepSize -> {Automatic, 2}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity]; Plot3D[#[x, t] // Abs // Evaluate, {t, 0, T}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100] & /@ sol` the result looks reasonable, is it fine for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @xzczd. It seems to work for this trial case. However, I find it very odd that an increase in the number of grid points would results in worse results. It gives me the impression these settings wouldn't hold when I start to change the parameters. I use version 13.0.1 for Apple's M1. I tried different values of PrecisionGoal/AccuracyGoal up to 12, DifferenceOrder up to 8, and I must keep the stepsize<=ax/2 to capture the modulation of Chi2 via g(x).

Comment: 1. It seems that the adaptive ODE solver of `NDSolve` isn't done a good job in this case, so for finer saptial grid you may need to choose smaller option value for `MaxStepSize`. 2. `PrecisionGoal`/`AccuracyGoal` should be the last thing to tackle, see this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871 3. My `pdetoode` might help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871