# Solution gets worse as I increase Precision and Accuracy goals

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

I am numerically solving the following ODE below.
If I set AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal both to 10 I get a solution that makes sense: constant and then damped oscillation.
However, all things equal, if I increase the Accuracy and Precision goals at some point the solution stops making sense. Why?

```
ti = 2 10^12;
tf = 2 10^14;
m=1;

s10 = NDSolve[{a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t] + m^2 (8 10^-21 t)^4 a[t] == 0, a[ti] == 1, a'[ti] == 0}, a[t], {t, ti, tf}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10];
s15 = NDSolve[{a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t] + m^2 (8 10^-21 t)^4 a[t] == 0, a[ti] == 1, a'[ti] == 0}, a[t], {t, ti, tf}, AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 15];
 
LogLinearPlot[{a[t] /. s10, a[t] /. s15}, {t, ti , tf}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: How is `m` defined?

Comment: Do you get error/warning messages?

Comment: Sorry, I edited to set m=1

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ti = 2 10^12;
tf = 2 10^14;

m = 1/4;

eqns = {a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t] +
     m^2 (8 10^-21 t)^4 a[t] == 0,
   a[ti] == 1, a'[ti] == 0};
```

From the documentation for [`PrecisionGoal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html), "In most cases, you must set WorkingPrecision to be at least as large as PrecisionGoal."

```
s10 = NDSolve[eqns, a[t], {t, ti, tf},
   WorkingPrecision -> 12,
   AccuracyGoal -> 10,
   PrecisionGoal -> 10];

s15 = NDSolve[eqns, a[t], {t, ti, tf},
   WorkingPrecision -> 17,
   AccuracyGoal -> 15,
   PrecisionGoal -> 15];

LogLinearPlot[{a[t] /. s10, a[t] /. s15}, {t, ti, tf}, 
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"s10", "s15"}, {.4, .6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I set m=1 instead of your 1/4. The solution blows up as it is.  If I decrease precision, for example to WorkingPrecision -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10 it behaves properly again. So now, for different reasons, it looks like the solution gets worse I as we increase precision...

Comment: As the value of `m` approaches `1` the `WorkingPrecision` in `NDSolve` must be increased even more above the specified `PrecisionGoal` **and** you must also specify a `WorkingPrecision` in the `LogLinearPlot`